# How to include a datetime parameter within a stored procedure along with string query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

My stored procedure is as follows,

```
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
   @FromDate datetime,
   @ToDate datetime

       --Select query
      DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)

      set @query='SELECT [col1] 
                  FROM [Table1]              
                  WHERE ([col2] BETWEEN '''+@FromDate+''' AND'''+@ToDate+''')'

       execute sp_executesql @query
```

Executing this string query results in following error,

"**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**"

Any one please help me to sort this out...

Comment: Add example FromDate and ToDate values to your question please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fundamental issue is that TSQL cannot implicitly convert datetime (or integer or floating point) into character data types. It actually goes backwards, it attempts to implicitly convert the character data to the datetime (int/floating point value) based on the data type precedence rules. This is what your error message is telling you by the way, it couldn't convert the strings to datetime values. You have to *explicitly* ask it to mash values into character strings.

This example demonstrates the principal with integers as they are easier to understand expected values.

```
DECLARE 
    @stringInt nvarchar(3)
,   @intint int

SELECT
    @stringInt = N'3'
,   @intint = 5

SELECT 
    @stringInt + @intint AS implicit_conversion
,   @stringInt + CAST(@intint AS nvarchar(5)) AS explicit_conversion
```

The value of the implicit conversion shows the @stringint is converted to integer first and then the + is treated as numeric addition and results in 8. The explicit conversion of @intint to a character data type results in the + sign treated as concatenation with the returned string of 35

```
implicit_conversion explicit_conversion
------------------- -------------------
8                   35
```

To solve your supplied problem, you must explicitly cast your datetime values to a character type so the query string can be concatenated as expected.

```
set @query='SELECT [col1] 
FROM [Table1]              
WHERE ([col2] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @FromDate, 121) +''' AND'''+ CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @ToDate, 121) +''')'
```

But as indicated above, you really don't want to do that for a number of reasons, SQL Injection being one of them. It also makes your maintenance much harder when you're slicing and dicing a query string in TSQL.

A better approach is to parameterize your query and use the power of [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). A nice thing about the sp_executesql parameter is that you don't have to use all the parameters supplied. Depending on what you are truly trying to do, this may be beneficial.

Sample table and data

```
CREATE TABLE 
dbo.table1
(col1 int, col2 datetime)

INSERT INTO
    dbo.table1
SELECT
3, '2009-04-06'
UNION ALL SELECT
1, '2001-09-11'
```

Demo of using parameters

```
DECLARE
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime

SELECT    
    @FromDate = '2005-03-17'
,   @ToDate = current_timestamp

DECLARE
    @query nvarchar(max)
SET @query = N'    
SELECT [col1] 
FROM [Table1]              
WHERE ([col2] BETWEEN @start AND @end)'

-- gratuitous use of parameter assignment here
-- could just as easily used @FromDate and @ToDate
-- in the @query and the parameter list
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
    @query
,   N'@start datetime, @end datetime'
,   @start = @FromDate
,   @end = @ToDate
```

Results

```
col1
3
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this error, and the vulnerabilities of SQL Injection, you should rewrite your query as follows:

```
@FromDate datetime,
@ToDate datetime

--Select query
 SELECT [col1] 
   FROM [Table1]              
  WHERE [col2] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: The actual query is not simple as the sample given. I had a requirement in which the query has to be executed dynamically.This is why i have created a string query.

Comment: I guess the next suggestion is to convert the dates to nvarchar before concatenating the string.  That should take care of the error.